# Freeze Columns ListView/GridView WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, gridview

I have a `ListView` which looks like this:

```
<ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
    <ListView>
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridView.Columns>
                ...
                </GridView.Columns>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
</ScrollViewer>
```

There are +-30 columns, so it's a very wide screen. When the user scrolls to the right, I still want him to know which column he's on. The first four columns contain that information (ID, name, ...), so I want to freeze these columns.

Also, I'm using [GridViewSort](http://www.thomaslevesque.com/2009/08/04/wpf-automatically-sort-a-gridview-continued/) so using two `ListView`s will cause the sort to not work anymore.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: @user3060520 I know it doesn't support it out of the box, so I'm looking if there is another way. Maybe by extending it? I am using external styles for the ListView, so I don't want to ditch it right away.

Comment: @user3060520 MS-FlexGrid is not available in WPF and ComponentOne's FlexGrid is paying.

Comment: @user3060520 Can you read that post please? They are using ComponentOne's FlexGrid and you need a paying license to use it. Evaluation version displays a message box on startup and that is something I don't want.

Comment: You should consider using a DataGrid insetad of a ListView and set its FrozenColumnCount property to 4. Then you will get both sorting and frozen column functionality for free.